# XAML concatenate binding Header property of Tabitem (TabControl)

Tags: wpf, xaml, tabcontrol

In my Xaml:

```
<TabItem Header="{Binding ContagemLista, Mode=OneTime, StringFormat=Listagem {0}}" Name="Listagem">
```

I must get `ContagemLista` value and concatenate this in my header property:
`Listagem (7)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of header might be lost the stringformat in the binding to solve that use the following:

```
 <TabControl>
        <TabItem >
            <TabItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ContagemLista, Mode=OneTime, StringFormat=Listagem {0}}"/>
            </TabItem.Header>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```